# EF6 code first: passing a parameter to a mapped delete stored procedure

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

We are using `EF6` with the `code first` approach. For the versioning of our records we are using `mapped stored procedures`.

This works great for the update since we pass all our values, including: `ModifiedBy` and `ModifiedOn`.

Now the update stored proc only takes the `Id`.
I was able to add the ModifiedBy to the procedure with the `[ConcurrencyCheck]` attribute. For the delete this worked but it makes my update fail.

Is there a good way to add more parameters to the delete stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is 3 months old but to answer your question directly I believe that the update is failing because you forgot to add the @ModifiedBy_Original parameter to the UPDATE stored proc.

I came to this page because we are trying something similar. We want to pass the person that did the delete as input parameter to the stored proc but we cannot figure out how.